# How do i know if i'm calling the COM object method correctly

Tags: c#, .net, com, directshow

I import COM object from C# using `ComImportAttribute`.

For example, I import as follows:

```
[ComImport] 
[Guid(ComLibrary.Constants.IGraphBuilderGuid)] 
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IGraphBuilder : IUnknown {

    [PreserveSig]
    public HResult AddFilter(
        [In] IBaseFilter filter,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String name
    );

    [PreserveSig]
    public HResult RemoveFilter(
        [In] IBaseFilter filter 
    );

    [PreserveSig]
    public HResult EnumFilters(
        [Out] IBaseFilter[] filters 
    );
}
```

How can I check if the COM object method I'm calling is correct?

I try to take into account the type of interface (IUnknown or IDispatch) and describe the methods   in the correct order, but the code in which I use imported objects does not give me the desired result, although similar code in C++ works as it should.

Therefore, I have suspicions that I am importing objects incorrectly again.

Comment: You can compare your signature with those in open source packages (or if you possibly imported the signature from those, you can just run sample code and see it's working as expected).

Comment: HResult would be translated to exception so there is no need to return it ... it just convention for languages which doesn't have exceptions  ... so EnumFilters should rather looks like `IBaseFilter[] EnumFilters()` ... but it seems like you didn't read answer to your previous question ... it is stated that when you are using `IUnknown` and not have all methods you need to **fill the gap between them** IUnknown just take vtable by index ...

Comment: Without understanding COM interop you should use 3rd party library which already did this ...

Comment: @Selvin
That's how I'm trying to understand COM.
I tried to fill the gap. The `strmif.h` file tells me that `AddFilter`, `RemoveFilter` and `EnumFilters` are located right after the IUnknown interface

Comment: @Selvin
So can you tell me where my gap is?

Comment: IUnknown should not be declared as a base with .NET as it's implicit (unless you put zero methods in it). You can look at how it's done for most Direct** technologies COM interface in this project https://github.com/smourier/DirectN. For example IGraphBuilder is defined here: https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/blob/master/DirectN/DirectN/Generated/IGraphBuilder.cs and IFilterGraph here https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/blob/master/DirectN/DirectN/Generated/IFilterGraph.cs your code doesn't seem to far but there are many ways to declare one interface

Comment: @SimonMourier
Thanks a lot for the answer, I will now be guided by your examples. I also found the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I managed to find the answer to my question. In order to see which COM function is called, let's use Visual Studio (I can't say for sure about other IDE`s) and the [`native code debugging mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2022).

For example, we define the following COM interface (gap is specified incorrectly here):

```
[ComImport]
[Guid(Constants.IBaseFilterGuid)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IBaseFilter {

    void _VtblGap0_8();

    [PreserveSig]
    public HResult QueryFilterInfo(
        [Out] out FilterInfo filterInfo
    );
}
```

First, you need to enable machine code debugging mode in the project properties.
[image]

After that, set a breakpoint on the function being checked (in our case, this is the `QueryFilterInfo` function).
[image]

Run the program in debug mode and press the `Step Into (F11)` button at the breakpoint. In the `Source Not Available` tab, click `View Disassembly`.
[image]

Аfter opening the `Disassembly` tab at the very top, you can see the name of the function that was called.
[image]

You may notice that the wrong function was called, and accordingly the `gap`-function is incorrect.

P.S.
English is not my native language, so in some moments I use a translator. Please forgive me